# Need to capture and respond to utterance not in slot

Tags: amazon-lex

Hello StackOverflow Friends:

Slots 1-5 below work great.

The problem is now I have to ask the user (after slot 5) "Describe the bug you encountered".

I suspect it is to broad / vague to put into a slot. I.e. if they say "the video crashed" and not "the player stopped" it keeps asking them to, "Describe the bug you encountered".

How do I respond with a "thank you" after the user types in, in their own words, the bug they encountered?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per this documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/howitworks-builtins-slots.html, there are no built-in slot types that can support free-form text/speech

As a workaround, you could create a slot of any type (e.g. AMAZON.NUMBER or AMAZON.Alphanumeric) so that you can use it to ask the 6th question for bug description. In addition, implement a code-hook lambda function for your intent.

At the end after 1-5 slots are filled, when this dummy slot is elicited with the required question, it will always turn up empty, however in the input event received by the code-hook lambda function- you can find the inputTranscript- this will capture what the caller has provided as input, even if the dummy slot value comes up as empty.

In your lambda function, you may ignore empty value of slot and go ahead with closing the Bot, by sending response as 'Fulfilled' after 1-5 are filled and you are received a non-empty value of inputTranscript for the 6th question.

Alternatively, you may return ElicitIntent (rather than ElicitSlot) from the code-hook lambda after slots 1-5 are filled. In this case you will not need to create a dummy slot as we are not using ElicitSlot. You will need to create a Fallback Intent and associate it with the lambda code-hook so that input transcript can be captured and saved as what the caller says may not match with utterances required for your original intent.

For more details on lambda code-hook for lex-intents, refer:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/programming-model.html#prog-model-lambda
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/lambda-input-response-format.html